# how to make CSS width property equal to the result of a mathematical expression

Tags: javascript, css, width

I'm trying to make the width property equal to `(100/3)%` because I am trying to divide the width evenly amongst 3 columns. But obviously this is not valid css. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy and paste the code in as text instead.

Comment: Ah, i didn't know. Will do so moving forward :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pure CSS method:

```css
th, td {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
}
```

Javascript method: You can get your table elements and assigns styles, try this:

```js
let th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
let td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

console.log(th, td)

for(let el of th){
    el.style.width = (100 / 3) + 'px';
}

for(let el of td){
    el.style.width = (100 / 3) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know you can do it like this, but is there a way to do it directly on the stylesheet without using javascript?

Comment: Maybe this ?? https://css-tricks.com/keep-math-in-the-css/

Comment: thank you! This is more of the kind of thing I was trying to do. Thank you both tho!

Comment: great! answer updated ...

Answer (score 3):

`calc` is the way to go.

Just make sure to leave a space between the operators and operands.

```
// This is correct
.class {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
}
```

```
// This produces an error
.class {
  width: calc(100%-5px);
}
```